# Serverless conditional function deployment by region

Tags: server, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

Following config is extracted from my `serverless.yml`

```
service: test-svc

provider:
  name: aws
  ...

functions:
  apiHandler:
    handler: index.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
  taskHandler:
    handler: task.handler
    events:
      - sqs:
          ...
  alexaHandler:
    handler: alexa.handler
    events:
     - alexaSmartHome: ...
```

I want to deploy `apiHandler` and `taskHandler` function in only `region-a`

And deploy `alexaHandler` in `region-b`, `region-c` and `region-d`.

If I execute the command `sls deploy --region us-east-1` all three functions will be deployed, but I don't need that. I need only 2 functions to be deployed.

1. Using `sls deploy function` is not an option because it only swaps zip file.
2. Putting alexaHandler in sub-directory with new `serverless.yml` didn't work because deployment only packs sub-directory and won't include code from the parent directory. (Many codes are shared between 3 function)

Any suggestion to deal with this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through all the serverless plugin list I found above requirement could be achieved through [serverless-plugin-select](https://github.com/FidelLimited/serverless-plugin-select)

Using this plugin we can select to deploy only a few functions from serverless.yml depending on `stage` or `region` value. In my case using region value.

Following is modified serverless.yml. `plugins` section added and `regions` key added in each function.

```
service: test-svc


plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-select

provider:
  name: aws
  ...

functions:
  apiHandler:
    ...
    regions:
      - us-west-2
  taskHandler:
    ...
    regions:
      - us-west-2
  alexaHandler:
    ...
    regions:
      - eu-west-1
      - us-east-1
      - us-west-2
```

With the above config, I use the following bash script to deploy for all region.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

serverless deploy --region eu-west-1
serverless deploy --region us-east-1
serverless deploy --region us-west-2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally select values in serverless.yml by storing the conditional functions in a custom variable like

```
### serverless.yml
provider:
  name: << aws or your provider >>
  runtime: << your runtime, eg nodejs8.10 >>
  region: << your aws region >>
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  custom:
    extraCode:
      dev:
      testing: ${file(testing_only/testing_endpoints.yml)}
      prod:

...

## and then at the functions section of serverless.yml

functions:
  - ${file(functions/someFunctionsInAFile.yml)}
  - ${file(functions/someMoreFunctions.yml)}
  - ${self:custom.extraCode.${self:provider.stage}}
```

When you deploy serverless you should pass in the command line option `--stage=myStageName` so that when you pass in `--stage=dev` or `--stage=prod` the last line in the function section will be blank and nothing will deployed.

If you pass in `--stage=testing` the last line in the functions sections will be filled with the file set in your custom variable section and then your test code will be deployed.